# referencing to the ios library in c++ when only using the iostream and iomanip libraries

Tags: c++, include, iostream

I want to ask a question about the ios library in C++.

I am a beginner in C++ and learning about the input/output streams - `iostream`

Consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> // required for manipulators

int main () {
    std::cout << "no boolalpha - default (10 == 10): " << (10 == 10) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "no boolalpha - default (10 == 20): " << (10 == 20) << std::endl;

    // set to true/false formatting
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "boolalpha (10 == 10): " << (10 == 10) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "boolalpha (10 == 20): " << (10 == 20) << std::endl;

    // setf method
    std::cout.setf(std::ios::boolalpha);
    std::cout << "boolalpha (10 == 10): " << (10 == 10) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "boolalpha (10 == 20): " << (10 == 20) << std::endl;

    // reset to default 0/1
    std::cout << std::resetiosflags(std::ios::boolalpha);
    std::cout << "Default (10 == 10): " << (10 == 10) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Default (10 == 20): " << (10 == 20) << std::endl;
    return 0;
```

I know that I can toggle the output stream to display boolean output by inserting `std::boolalpha` into `std::out`.

However, I can also use the `setf` method to toggle the flag too:

```
std::cout.setf(std::ios::boolalpha);
```

However, the argument supplied to the `setf` method makes reference to the `ios` library classes, although I have not imported the `ios` library in the header files.

This code still works.

Why does this work? I thought I need to declare the `<ios>` header file to make this work although the code compiles perfectly.

[image: ios library hierarchy, for reference]

Answer (score 2):

The `<iostream>` header includes `<ios>`, [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream).

Comment: oh so `<iostream>` includes `<ios>` when implemented in the header file, right?